# What does parallel binding mean in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp

I see the binding of `recur` is "parallel", however I don't get what that means.

I've tested the code below:

```
(defn parallelTest
  "parallel binding test of recur "
  []
  (loop [vectorA [1 2 3 4 5]
         A (first vectorA)]
    (if-not (= A nil)
      (do (println vectorA) (println A)
        (recur (rest vectorA) (first vectorA)))) ;Recur!
    ))
(parallelTest)
```

the output is

```
user=> 
[1 2 3 4 5]
1
(2 3 4 5)
1
(3 4 5)
2
(4 5)
3
(5)
4
()
5
nil
```

so I assume the bindings are happened **simultaneously** instead of one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sequential binding**

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

Here

1. `1` is evaluated
2. then bound to `a`
3. then `2` is evaluated
4. then bound to b

**Parallel binding**

```
a,b = 1,2
```

Here,

1. `1` and `2` are evaluated, either in a determined order (such as left to right) or not, depending on the language specifications
2. the two results are bound to `a` and `b`, respectively.

If the expressions (here `1` and `2`) are *independant* and *side-effect free*, it doesn't matter which binding you use,  but in parallel you need to be aware of the exact evaluation order.

Now, in your case,

1. first `(rest vectorA)`
2. then `(first vectorA)` are evaluated (left to right)
3. then the results are bound to `vectorA` and `A`, respectively.

which is a parallel binding, as opposed to for example a `let` binding in Clojure which is sequential.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in computer science, "in parallel" will generally mean simultaneously, as opposed to "sequentially" (in a specified order) or "concurrently" (in an arbitrary indeterminate order, which could be parallel or sequential with arbitrary sequence). Parallel binding is typically understood to mean that a result (left hand side) of one binding is not in the scope of the creation (right hand side) of another (as opposed to sequential binding, as seen in Clojure's `let` statement).